# How to cover all the height of a div with a button?

Tags: css

I have a menu and I have to cover all a div height with a button. I really need the button because of its features (I can disable it from CSS or JS for example).

So, imagine you have a resizable menu (try resizing the window [in the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgbcL5t9/5/)) and it can have different height values.

```
<div id="header-menu">
    <div id="header-back-button" onclick="alert('click')">
        <button id="back-button">Back</button>
    </div>
    <div id="header-title">
        <h1>This is my so so so long title</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="header-next-button">
        <button id="next-button">
            <img id = "imgMenu" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-512.png"></img>
    </button>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#header-menu{
    display: table;
    width:100%
}
#header-back-button {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 15%;
    min-width: 30px;
    height: 25px;
    background: orange;
}
#header-title {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 70%;
    min-width: 40px;
    background: yellow;
}
#header-next-button {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 15%;
    min-width: 30px;
    height: 25px;
    background: orange;
}
button {
    background: red;
    border: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#imgMenu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Can you hel me?

Answer (score 0):

change your CSS to this:

```
   #header-menu {
    display: table;
    width:100%
}
#header-back-button {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 15%;
    min-width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    background: orange;
}
#header-title {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 70%;
    min-width: 40px;
    background: yellow;
}
#header-next-button {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 15%;
    min-width: 30px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFA500;
    padding: 0px !important;
    vertical-align: top;
}
button {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #F00;
    border: 0px none;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0px !important;
}
#imgMenu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[see updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sg80yLuz/2/)

Comment: but the height can't be fixed (not 25px;) because it changes. Try to resize width and height of your "result window" fiddle... You will see some weard behaviour

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake in the code because I did it in Inspector, I edited it so now it's the correct code. However, there's a min width where the button won't take the height anymore. That's because of your h1 element, you'll need to change your html in order to make that column grow as well